# Fit decoRule to picture lentgh

Tags: graphics, decorations

I am using decoRule to draw a line under my figure and before the caption. I would like to have this line with the same lenght of my picture.
[image]

the code I am using is the following:

```
 \begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{stereolithography}
       \label{fig:sla}
  \end{subfigure}
  %
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{dlp1}
    \label{fig:dlp}
  \end{subfigure}
  \decoRule
  \caption[Schematic of Vat Photopolymerization.]{a) Schematic of top-cured laser based machine, Stereolithography. b) Schematic of bottom-cured Digital Light Processing (DLP) machine. Courtesy of 3D Printing Industry \parencite{3d_printing_industry_2016}.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Just change the definition of `\decoRule` to take an optional argument for the line length and use `\decoRule[\textwidth]`. For more concrete help, extend the snippet to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), which would show, how/where `\decoRule` is defined.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek sorry for the late reply. Here is how I defined DecoRule

\newcommand{\decoRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}}

Is it possible to tell somehow that the length should be the same as the figure in which I am using it?

Comment: It should be the width, that is used as option for `\includegraphics`. Make a MWE, which show, how/where `subfigure` is defined. Also the specified length values do not look correct. The outer environment `subfigure` uses `.6\textwidth`, but the image is included with `width=\textwidth`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Not to mention `.6\textwidth` + space + `.6\textwidth` fitting inside `\texwidth` ...

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, your question is unanswerable since none but you know how `\decoRule` is defined.

There is a `\decorule` defined by the **decorule** package. However, it looks nothing like the rule in your image, so presumably it isn't that. In fact, the rule in your image looks like a bog-standard rule.

If so, then you can just set `\vrule` to the appropriate width - for one example.

The main issue is that your code will give bad boxes because you cannot fit 120% of the `\textwidth` plus an additional space into a `\textwidth` text block and expect things to work nicely.

The following uses **chngpage** to adjust the left and right margins for the image and rule, reverting to the standard settings for the caption. This eliminates bad boxes.

Obviously, I changed the images. I'm sure you'll agree these are a considerable improvement. A pedant might quibble over the relevance of the caption and the transformation of the citation into a question mark. However, sometimes you just have to take your cats where you can find them and damn the critics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,chngpage,calc}
\newlength\fulltextwidth
\setlength\fulltextwidth{\textwidth}
\newlength\fullpicwidth
\setlength\fullpicwidth{1.2\textwidth+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-.1\fulltextwidth-\fboxrule-\fboxsep}{-.1\fulltextwidth-\fboxsep-\fboxrule}
    \fbox{%
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\fulltextwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cauldron}
        \label{fig:sla}
      \end{subfigure}%
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\fulltextwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cathod}
        \label{fig:dlp}
      \end{subfigure}%
    }
    \par
    \vrule height 1pt depth 1pt width \fullpicwidth
    \par
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \caption[Schematic of Vat Photopolymerization.]{a) Schematic of top-cured laser based machine, Stereolithography. b) Schematic of bottom-cured Digital Light Processing (DLP) machine. Courtesy of 3D Printing Industry \cite{3d_printing_industry_2016}.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: cauldron and cats]

Comment: decoRule is defined as following:

\newcommand{\decoRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}}

Is there a way to have the lenght of this line as the same of the figure I am using?

Comment: You mean `height .2pt depth .2pt` rather than `height 1pt depth 1pt`? You can make the dimensions whatever you like.

Comment: @AlexisCharalambis Note that the example I gave shows you how to make the rule match the width of the figure. I'm not really certain what you're asking. You must surely be getting complaints about bad boxes with your code. These are telling you stuff isn't fitting together properly - you can't expect the results to fit nicely in this case!

Answer (score 0):

You could center the horizontal line by using `\centering`. You also need to leave an empty line before placing the `\centering` command for it to not center all of your subfigures. So your code should look like this.

```
\begin{figure}
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{stereolithography}
      \label{fig:sla}
 \end{subfigure}
 %
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{dlp1}
   \label{fig:dlp}
 \end{subfigure}

% Leave an empty line then add \centering before adding \decoRule
 \centering
 \decoRule 
 \caption[Schematic of Vat Photopolymerization.]{a) Schematic of top-cured laser based machine, Stereolithography. b) Schematic of bottom-cured Digital Light Processing (DLP) machine. Courtesy of 3D Printing Industry \parencite{3d_printing_industry_2016}.}
\end{figure}
```

I am not sure why it works. It probably has to do with new paragraphs and stuff...